# How to connect to Membership DB from an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

I am trying to configure my site with ASP.NET Membership to deal with the whole user's login.
For some reason, I can't connect to my DB from the ASP configuration screen. All the TCP/IP are enabled in the SQL server configuration, but for some reason my website can't connect.

Comment: Have you started [aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862.aspx)? Have a look [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/moving-to-aspnet-20/membership) for further informations.

Comment: thank
i have used this tool already, do i need to manually set the connection string first?

Comment: Are you using the SQL Express database (app_data/aspnetdb.mdf)?

Comment: no, i want to use my sql server 2008 R2 express. is there a way to use this instead of a local DB?

Comment: Have you read the above article?  You need to configure it in the machine.config or web.config. http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/08/26/Using-connection-strings-from-web.config-in-ASP.NET-v2.0.aspx

Comment: When you say you can't connect, are you getting an error message?  Or is your app just pointing to the wrong database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant things to check for this issue (that come to my mind) are all in the Web.config file for your application.

You should have a connection to the SQL server set up:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;User Id=sqlUser;Password=sqlPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

<sub>Note: the "connection string" attribute there should point to your SQLExpress instance.</sub>

You should have a membership provider pointing to that connection (with some additional setup parameters:

```
<membership>
    <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
    </providers>
</membership>
```

And (possibly) you should have your authentication mode set to forms:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
</authentication>
```